# JPA/Hibernate OnetoMany preventing duplicate children

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There are a few different questions around this topic that have had answers but from what I can see many answers are old or don't make clear sense to me.

Let's say I have an `Entity`/`Table`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ParentTable")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    private List<Child> children;

    public Parent(String childLabel){
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.children.add(new Child(childLabel));
    }

    // Get/Set/Constructors

}
```

Then `Child` as:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String label;

    public Child(String label){
         this.label = label;
    }

    // Get/Set/Constructors

}
```

And I then construct some parents by:

```
String childLabel = "child-label";
Parent a = new Parent(childLabel);
Parent b = new Parent(childLabel);
// Save both parents to a db
```

It creates two instances of the child in the table with different IDs. I understand that it is because different instances of the `Child` are being created and then saved separately.

But how should I go about changing my design to ensure only one instance of two identical children is saved and referenced? I have tried constructing the child then giving to the parents but then I get a primary key error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your constructor to take a Child instead:

```
public Parent(Child childLabel){
    this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    this.children.add(childLabel);
}
```

If you want to enforce uniqueness for the label on Child then change the column definition in Child

```
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private String label;
```

If more than one Parent needs to reference the same child then you may need to use a ManyToMany type reference instead of One to Many.

Comment: Thank you so much! Did have to change to a ManyToMany also but that's my foolishness